# Electron - How to sniff http request body

Tags: electron

I have a simple electron app which loads a certain website.
This website is doing http get/post requests. I want to sniff the body of the server responses.

I already checked out the [webRequest](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-request) module which seemed pretty nice. Unfortunetely, it handles all data EXCEPT the body.

How can I sniff the body of the server responses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out that this is not possible. Also its not a an Electron issue, rather a chromium one - Electron just wraps the chromium API.

Finally I managed to inject a javascript (inside the api service) which forwards me all data received from the server via ipc
https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main